# Read multiple files at runtime (dataflow template)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I am trying to build a dataflow template.

The goal is to read ValueProvider that will tell me what files to read.
Then for each files I need to read and enrich data with the object.
I have tried this:

```
        p.apply(Create.of(options.getScheduleBatch()))
            .apply(ParDo.of(StringScheduleBatchToFileReceivedFn.of()))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<FileReceived, PCollection<EventRow>>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void process(ProcessContext c) {
                    FileReceived fileReceived = c.element();
                    Broker broker = configuration.getBroker(fileReceived.getBrokerId());
                    PCollection<EventRow> eventRows = p
                            .apply(TextIO.read().from(fileReceived.getUri()))
                            .apply(ParDo.of(StringToEventRowFn.of(broker, fileReceived, options.getJobName())));
                    c.output(eventRows);
                }
            }));
```

But I have the following error:

Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Unable to provide a Coder for org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.

I would love to find a better way than reading the file by myself using gcs client.

Do you have any tips ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:**

You're trying to emit a `PCollection` as an output of your `ParDo`. This doesn't work.

**Details:**

`PCollection` is an abstraction that represents a potentially unbounded collection of elements. Applying a transformation to a `PCollection` gives you another `PCollection`. One of the transformations you can apply is a `ParDo`. `ParDos` make element-wise transforms. When applying a `ParDo` you're expressing - "take this `PCollection` and make another one by converting all elements within it by applying that `ParDo`".

One of the things that makes the processing effective is ability to execute everything in parallel, e.g. converting a lot of elements at once on multiple execution nodes (e.g. VMs/machines) by running the same `ParDo` on each against different elements. And you can't explicitly control whether any specific transform will happen on the same execution node or another one, it's part of the underlying system design how to optimize this. But to enable this you must be able to potentially pass elements around between execution nodes and persist them for aggregation. Beam supports this by requiring you to implement `Coders` for elements. Coders are a serialization mechanism that allows Beam to convert an element (represented by a java object) to a byte array which can then be passed to the next transformation (that can potentially happen on another machine) or storage. For example, Beam needs to be able to encode the elements that you output from a `ParDo`. Beam knows how to serialize some types, but it cannot infer everything automatically, you have to provide coders for something that cannot be inferred.

Your example looks like this: take some `PCollection`, and convert it into another `PCollection` by applying a `ParDo` to each element, and that `ParDo` transforms each input element into a `PCollection`. This means that as soon as element gets processed by a `ParDo` you have to encode it and pass it to the next transformation. And the question here is - how do you encode and pass a (potentially unbounded) `PCollection` to the next transform or persist it for aggregation?

Beam doesn't support thisat the moment, so you will need to choose another approach.

In your specific case I am not sure if in Beam out of the box you can simply use a stream of filenames and the convert them into sub-pipelines for processing the lines in the files.

**Workarounds:**

Few approaches I can think of to bypass this limitation:

- If your file names have a known pattern, you can specify the pattern in `TextIO` and it can read the new files as they arrive.
- If they don't have a known pattern, you can potentially write another pipeline to rename the files names so that they have common name pattern and then use the pattern in `TextIO` in another pipeline.
- If feasible (e.g. files fit in memory), you could probably read the files contents with pure java `File` API, split them into rows and emit those rows in a single `ParDo`. Then you can apply the same `StringToEventRowFn` in the following `ParDo`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer, I have change the approach.
I used FileIO.matchAll + FileIO.readMatches then for each line read I return a KV the key is the filename and the value a line.
And on the site I built up a PCollection view as a Map and I will fetch the value using KV's key.